# JMS message text cannot be seen

Tags: jms

My JMS message can be inserted into JMS queue successfully. And the data length is not zero but the text cannot be seen. It looks like empty. The character encoding is 'UTF-8'.

Can you think of what is the possible cause?

Comment: What JMS provider are you using?

Comment: Oracle Advanced Queue

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer somewhere else.

When the size of the text is < 4k, it is shown in USER_DATA.TEXT_VC
When the size of the text is >= 4k, it is saved in USER_DATA.TEXT_LOB

That's why it cannot be seen.